# INSERT INTO not working on Service-Based Database

Tags: c#, sql

I'm not sure what is the problem specifically but I can't get to Insert in my database.

I use .mdf or Service-Based Database so i figured it may have something to do with this

This is the code I use for my Insert. I tried the query in Server Explorer Query and it is 100% working

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Db.ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Account Values('User','Password','Department')", con))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I also tried debugging for hours.

I have another statement that does Select query and it works so I am sure with my connection string

I also tried this

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(Db.ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Account Values('User','Password','Department')", cn))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO Account Values('User','Password','Department')";
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
```

All those 3 did not work.

EDIT:
I found the problem, I just realized when I open my Project Folder. 
My Select Statement is looking at my .mbf on my project folder
while the insert statement is going in Project/Bin/Debug Folder which is very weird because they have the same connection string.

Can someone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Is there any exception ?

Comment: Does the connection string user have permissions to perform `INSERT` and `UPDATE`?

Comment: No Exception, weired part is that it says it is affected. 

Yes all default permission are done

Comment: Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)

Comment: Want to answer it so that people the same problem can see the solution? yup that link is very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you construct your statement like this, without specifying fields, the error comes from the fields being in the wrong order or you are skipping a field.

It is a best practice to specify the fields as well as values, like this:

```
Insert INTO Account (fld1,fld2,fld3) Values('User','Password','Department')
```

replace fldx with the actual field names

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Check your credentials to make sure they are able to insert into the database/table. What isn't clear here is WHAT isn't working.

Comment: I saw the problem, I edited my body right now. The problem now goes with the mbf target which is very weird